# GDB pid changes when connected automatically and quit

Tags: c, linux, gdb

I am trying to attach an existing process, run some commands and print the required information. However, when I do it, I see that the PID of the process is changed (with `killed`) command being displayed.

---

Code

```
     1  #include <iostream>
     2  #include <unistd.h>
     3  using namespace std;
     4
     5
     6  int main()
     7  {
     8      do
     9      {
    10          static int s = 100;
    11          s = s+1;
    12          sleep (3);
    13      } while(1);
    14      return 0;
    15  }
    16
```

---

GDB commands

```
> cat /tmp/command.txt    
set pagination off
set logging file /home/testgrp/gdb.txt
set logging on
b sample.cc:11
commands 1
    p s
end
run 1
quit
```

---

Output

```
root@198.18.81.198:/desktop/user1/workspace# ps -eaf | grep out
root     16724  8877  0 08:25 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color=auto out
root@198.18.81.198:/desktop/user1/workspace# cat /home/testgrp/gdb.txt
cat: /home/testgrp/gdb.txt: No such file or directory
root@198.18.81.198:/desktop/user1/workspace# ./a.out &
[1] 16762
root@198.18.81.198:/desktop/user1/workspace# gdb --batch-silent -x=/tmp/command.txt -p 16762
[1]+  Killed                  ./a.out
root@198.18.81.198:/desktop/user1/workspace# ps -eaf | grep out
root     16805     1  0 08:25 pts/1    00:00:00 /desktop/user1/workspace/a.out 1
root     16823  8877  0 08:25 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color=auto out
root@198.18.81.198:/desktop/user1/workspace# cat /home/testgrp/gdb.txt
Breakpoint 1 at 0x400711: file sample.cc, line 11.
$1 = 100
A debugging session is active.

    Inferior 1 [process 16805] will be detached.

Quit anyway? (y or n) [answered Y; input not from terminal]
```

---

Question

1. How do I get the required information without changing the PID of the process?
2. More importantly, why does the pid change and previous PID is `killed`

---

Appendix

GDB version

```
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.7.1-0ubuntu5~14.04.2aka8.0.1) 7.7.1
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
```

Comment: detached is not killed. your process is still running when gdb exits.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre : Why do I see the pid changed for the process? You can see in the output the change in PID. I want to capture the information without change in pid.

Comment: Sorry I don't think this is possible. Check that process 16805 (or whatever it is) is still running. Unless gdb crashes it. But it shouldn't respawn as another process. not possible.

Comment: you didn't perform a `ps -eaf | grep out` _after_ exiting gdb. That is the important info you need to show.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre : I have done already done it. Check the command after the `gdb` command.  That is exactly what I am doing (checking the pid)

Comment: PID of a process cannot possibly change. GDB `run` command kills the process being debugged and starts a fresh instance. If you want to attach to a process and let it continue, don't use `run`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in the last two lines of your gdb scripts

```
run 1
quit
```

"run 1" will restart the program it is debugging with argument "1". by default, it should ask you to confirm restart or not.But you have an argument "--batch-silent" when you starting gdb. so your process restart without message.

delete "--batch-silent" and last 2 lines of your gdb script then you can break and debug.
"b sample.cc:11" will stop in system function sleep, you can change it to other line if you feel confuse . (I recommend you to read some simpler demos before using gdb,so many cmd will let beginner feel confuse)